# How do I stop View/Edit tabs appearing on Taxonomy driven Pages when I am not logged in?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I have a View and Edit button appearing on pages that are Taxonomy driven, even when I am not logged in (and in Incognito Mode).

These pages use the URL `/taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` and Views, using info from the URL, are used to display certain data on these pages. For example, with `/cars/honda/civic` 'cars', 'honda' and 'civic' would be used in the Views to show relevant information about Honda Civics.

The issue is that whilst there is no View and Edit buttons appearing on the base `/cars` page, they are appearing on every sub page (`/cars/honda`, `/cars/toyota/camry`, etc).

I can't find anything out of the ordinary in Permissions.

Would any one know what I could do to stop this?

(PS clicking the Edit button whilst not logged in does nothing - just takes you to 403 page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to someone not surrounding this code with a permissions checker, eg:

```
 if (!user_access('administer nodes')) {
    return;
  }
```